# Heroku css static file name changed

Tags: css, django, heroku

Django code serves the static css file properly locally but doesn't when pushed to Heroku.

The push process includes running collectstatic, which appears to append something to the css file name. Viewing the source of the Heroku served index page is this:

```
<link href="/static/mycssfile.cba06cddbdea.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

The file exists on heroku in the expected static folder as mycssfile.css.

All the admin static files are collected and served properly. Here are the static settings. This works when served by foreman.

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Put static files such as css in a separate folder such as 'mystatic' and list that folder in STATICFILES_DIRS, then run `manage.py findstatic mycssfile.css` to make sure it's found. Then when uploaded to Heroku collectstatic finds the file. All clear now.